# ScalaCheck nested Gen

Tags: scalatest, scalacheck

In ScalaCheck it seems that a mapped/flatMapped `Gen` will fail as soon as any inner gen has a value filtered out.  E.g. (using ScalaTest)

```
class ScalaCheckGen extends FreeSpec with GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks {
  "Fails" in {
    forAll(Gen.listOfN(100, arbitrary[Int].suchThat(_ % 2 == 0))){
      _ => assert(true)}

    //Gave up after 0 successful property evaluations. 51 evaluations were discarded.
  }

  "Passes" in {
    forAll(Gen.listOfN(100, arbitrary[Int].map(_ * 2))){
      _ => assert(true)}
  }
}
```

Suppose the trivial workaround above didn't work because the `suchThat` condition was complex.  How could this be rewritten to work while still using a `suchThat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `suchThat` with `retryUntil`, but beware of infinite loops.